# Can't add bootstrap classes to javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

```
var result = document.getElementById("result")

//can't add bootstrap classes to <div> and <table>
<div class="container"><table class="table">

result.innerHTML = "<div><table><thead><tr><td>Column A</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your code the outer div doesn't seem to have an id attached to it, call the div like:

```
<div id="result>
```

To add bootstrap to your html you have to first import the css file  and put it in the head element of your html like:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Then add the javascript, jquery, and popper.js file to the end of the body of the html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also make sure to add your javascript to the html using the script tag as seen above or put it b/w the script tags

```
<script>
some js
</script>
```